# Chrome loses sound input and mouse with Thunderbolt setup

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, thunderbolt

Have a couple of weird things going on with Chrome and external devices on my MacBook Air 2014 (OS 10.11.6). I have a setup where I have several devices connected to my MacBook via Thuderbolt port connected to a Belkin Thunderbolt 2 Express Dock HD (namely, monitor, wireless keyboard, wireless mouse, headphones, Ethernet and external disk).

First, when I exit Chrome, my mouse sometimes stops working. Just does not react to anything. This has been happening pretty consistently with Chrome, and only Chrome - did not notice any other app behaving like that. After I disconnect the Thunderbolt cable and reconnect it again everything works again. The touchpad works fine all the time.

Second, sometimes (usually after disconnecting Thunderbolt cable and reconnecting it again) Chrome stops interacting with the microphone. I am talking about internal one - Chrome just ignores it, e.g. when I use Google Hangout, nothing can be heard. If I restart Chrome - without doing anything else - it starts working again. System sound configuration has internal mic selected and does not have any problem detecting and using it - but Chrome does.

Anybody encountered such effects or has any idea what could be causing it? It sounds rather weird but I had it happen multiple times and by now I'm pretty sure the conditions are as described, though still have no idea why.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide the specific MacBook Air and the version of macOS  you are using.  Also have you tried to see if the problem occurs in Safe Mode and/or a different browser?

Comment: Did not notice it happening with other browsers. But I mainly use Chrome, so it is possible I don't use them enough for it to happen (it doesn't happen every time I exit Chrome, but frequently enough I have noticed the pattern). 
Added the specs to the question.

Comment: Actually, noticed it happening with Brave browser (built on Chrome opensource engine) too, so it's probably something in Chrome code...